# Values of limits through known derivative at a point

Tags: limits, derivatives

In our differential calculus chapter, one of the first exercises given to us goes as it follows:

Let $f: \mathbb {R} \rightarrow   \mathbb {R}$ be such that $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=1$. Determine the following limits:

(i) $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(2x)}{x}  $

(ii) $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x^2)}{x}  $

(iii) $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)-(f(-x))}{x}  $

If I had $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}  $, the limit would be equal to 1, because of $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}  $ and by removing $f(0)$ and $0$ since they are both zero. How should I approach this exercise? I have tried going by the definition of derivative at a point but have reached nothing outside of the case just described. I would appreciate help very much.

Comment: Try forming these expressions in the form $\lim_{u \to 0} \frac{f(u)}{u}$, where $u$ is a function of $x$ that tends to $0$ as $x \to 0$. For example, $\frac{f(x^2)}{x} = \frac{f(x^2)}{x^2} \cdot x$, which tends to $1 \cdot 0 = 0$. Try the others in similar fashion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: try making a change of variables. For instance, by writing $y = 2x$ we can say things like $\lim_{x \to 0} f(2x) = \lim_{y \to 0} f(y)$. Then, try implementing your original idea.